# adding an extra attribute inside html tag through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

assume we have a set of html tags like

```
<div id="slide1" class="slide"></div>
<div id="slide2" class="slide"></div>
<div id="slide3" class="slide"></div>
```

I am trying to add an extra attribute in to the div tag like `key='post'` from the array `[post, get, search]`  for each tags respectively. 
Is it possible to do that using javascript??

I would also like to knw what if the input was hash instead of array like

```
 {"post" : ["0","1"], "get": ["0","2"], "search": ["2","1"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, just use element.setAttribute() like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("slide1");
element.setAttribute('key','post');
```

Comment: I'm not, I was first with my answer and then decided to adapt my example to the OP's code. Not a miracle that I end up with almost identical code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var attrs = ['post', 'get', 'search'];
for (var i = 0, n = attrs.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var el = document.getElementById('slide' + (i + 1));
    el.setAttribute('key', attrs[i]);
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using jQuery (and assuming that only these three elements have the `slide` class):

```
var attrs = ['post', 'get', 'search'];
$('.slide').attr('key', function(i) {
    return attrs[i];
});
```

The updated part of the question (using an object "hash" instead of an array) wouldn't work because an object has no defined ordering.  You *can* get the labels but they will not appear in a deterministic order:.

```
var myobj = {"post" : ["0","1"], "get": ["0","2"], "search": ["2","1"]};
var attrs = Object.keys(myobj);
... // as above
```

See the MDN site for [documentation for `Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), including a shim for older browsers.

Comment: what if the input was hash instead of array like {"post" : ["0","1"], "get": ["0","2"], "search": ["2","1"]}

Comment: @SamDaSilva what do you expect the HTML output to look like in the hash example?  p.s. if that's really the case, you should update your question because the answer will look quite different.

Comment: keys should have the same values as that of array..qustion updated

Comment: @SamDaSilva but what do the values inside the array represent (if anything)?  An object has no order, so you can't assume that `post` will go into element 0.

Comment: ignore the elements inside the array...I just wanted to add a hash

Comment: @SamDaSilva yeah, you can't do that.  A hash has no defined order.

Comment: so how do we tackle this situation? is it possible if we dont care about the order..

Comment: @SamDaSilva sure, if you don't care about the order you can use `Object.keys(myObj)` to get an array of the keys.  Use a shim for older browsers that don't natively support that function.

Answer (score 0):

Set Attribute is what you are looking for :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute

```
var d = document.getElementById("slide1"); 
d.setAttribute("key", "post");
```